# How to use Ruplacer in another function (Rust)

Tags: string, replace, rust

I've tried to write a function to replace string in a directory. And I founded a performance library written in Rust. https://github.com/TankerHQ/ruplacer, but the documentations only works in CLI. Now I can not custom the library to a function like that:

```rust
fn replace(path, foo, bar) {
  ruplacer(path, foo, bar)
}
```

Comment: It's not really documented because it's not really intended to be used as a library, but here is the API for the ruplacer crate: https://docs.rs/ruplacer/0.4.3/ruplacer/